# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() - each time I run my php file it shows me this error

Tags: php, mysql, dll

Im using Windows 8.1, using xampp as a server
im a newbie, learning PHP, i have this issue in connecting php to the database

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path=".;\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

---

also removed the comments from the php.mysql.dll

```
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
```

kindly help me, solve this issue... :(

Comment: `extension=php_mysql.dll` comment this line restart you xampp and then use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` in your code

Comment: welcome to 2016, we now have `mysqli`.

Comment: If you have installed PHP7 with xampp, then you don't have the MySQL extension, only MySQLi or PDO - MySQL has been deprecated for some years now, and finally removed

Answer (score 0):

That's because **mysql** extension has been removed. Judging from that I would say that you are using an outdated lesson.

The new extension is **mysqli** and so, instead of mysql_connect, use mysqli_connect. Take into account that the parameters might be in different order for mysqli.